# How should I insert html input data into a Django database

Tags: python, html, django, sqlite

I can't figure out how to fix this problem. I'm trying to insert some data from a html form into a small simple Django database; SQLite if I'm right.

I tried to follow tutorials and did allot of searching online but it seems like I've hit tutorial hell.

my question is: How can I achieve putting data from the text input field on the html file into the Django database?

Here's what I've got so far:

the HTML:

```
    <h1>Create a Post </h1>
    <form action="check" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
        artiest: <input type="text" name="artiest"/><br/>
        song: <br/>
        <textarea cols="35" rows="8" name="song">
        </textarea><br/>
        <button type="submit" value="Post"/> </button>
    </form>
```

the views.py

```
def check(request):

    post=Post()
    post.artiest= request.POST.get('artiest')
    post.song= request.POST.get('song')
    post.save()

    return render(request, 'spotifylist/check.html')
```

the models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    artiest = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    song = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    naam = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.artiest
```

the urls.py:

```
urlpatterns= [
re_path('^home/', views.home, name = 'spotifylist-home'),
re_path('help/', views.help, name = 'spotifylist-help'),
re_path('check/', views.check, name = 'spotifylist-check'),
```

]

so what happens is: when I submit the page refreshes and doesn't add the data. Which is added to the home page with in the views.py:

```
def home(request):
context = {
    'posts' : Post.objects.all()
}
return render(request,'spotifylist/home.html', context)
```

Thanks Tim! for noting the `action="check"` error, though it didn't fix my problem!

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: did you run it in console to see error messages in console? Maybe it has some problem and it display error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Model
    from django.db import models

    # Create your models here.
    class CoachDetailsModel(models.Model):

         coach_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
         name=models.CharField(max_length=100,help_text="Enter FullName")
         email=models.EmailField(max_length=100,help_text="Enter Email id")
         contact=models.BigIntegerField(help_text="Enter Mobile Number" ,null=True)
         password=models.CharField(max_length=100,help_text="Enter Password")
         coach_status=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='pending',help_text="Enter Password")

         def __str__(self):
             return self.email

         class Meta:
             db_table="Coach_details"

# Views
    def coach_register(request):
      if request.method == "POST":
            name= request.POST.get('name')
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            contact = request.POST.get('contact')
            password = request.POST.get('password')

            CoachDetailsModel.objects.create(name=name,email=email,contact=contact,password=password)
      return render(request,'coach/coach-register.html')

      ### url
    path('coach-register',coachviews.coach_register,name='coach_register'),

# Html page
                                      <form method="POST" id="contactForm" name="contactForm" class="contactForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                        <div class="row">
                                        
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="label" for="subject">Enter UserName</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="subject" placeholder="UserName">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="label" for="subject">Enter Contact</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact" id="subject" placeholder="Contact">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="label" for="subject">EMAIL-ADDRESS</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="subject" placeholder="Email">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <div class="form-group-col-6">
                                                    <label class="label" for="subject">PASSWORD</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" id="subject" placeholder="Password">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        
                                        
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <div class="form-group col-9">
                                                    <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary">
                                                    <div class="submitting"></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
```

Comment: in my case, i need "action="{% url 'yoururl' %}"" into form tag

Answer (score 0):

It was solved thanks to Naser Fazal khan.

my html form was in on home page.

so i simply just moved from my 'check' method.

```
    if request.method == "POST":
    artiest= request.POST.get('artiest')
    song = request.POST.get('song')
    naam = request.POST.get('naam')
    link = request.POST.get('link')

    Post.objects.create(artiest=artiest,song=song,naam=naam,link=link)
return render(request,'spotifylist/home.html', context)
```

to my home views method:

```
def home(request):
context = {
    'posts' : Post.objects.all()
}
if request.method == "POST":
    artiest= request.POST.get('artiest')
    song = request.POST.get('song')
    naam = request.POST.get('naam')
    link = request.POST.get('link')

    Post.objects.create(artiest=artiest,song=song,naam=naam,link=link)
return render(request,'spotifylist/home.html', context)
```

and i've added an extra line on the method

```
Post.objects.create(artiest=artiest,song=song,naam=naam,link=link)
```

and this is what happens when you just blindly follow tutorials! thanks everyone for the effort.